# Angular: how to set 'value' different than displayed value in options?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my angular SPA I am using a `<select><option ng-repeat...></select>` construct, this way

```
<div ng-init="hours = [ '9:00', '10:00' ]">
  <select name="eta" ng-model="reservation.eta">
    <option ng-repeat="hour in hours track by $index" ng-value="hour">{{ 'We arrive at' | translate }} {{hour}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The problem is that in the `value` of each `option` I get "We arrive at HOUR" string (the same as in the displayed value, which is correct), and not the hour alone, as I want...

What do I miss?

*N.B.: Please do not suggest using `ng-options` since I was forced to drop it for some problem setting the selected and disabled first option (as a placeholder)... :-(*

Comment: `ng-options` shouldn't have caused any problem with a default placeholder option....  while using `ng-repeat` probably works in this scenario, I would encourage you to ask about this other problem, since `ng-options` is really the preferred way to handle most select situations.

Comment: Yes, I'll do it ASAP...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use ng-value here.  Just use value.

```
<div ng-init="hours = [ '9:00', '10:00' ]">
   <select name="eta" ng-model="reservation.eta">
      <option ng-repeat="hour in hours track by $index" value="{{hour}}">{{ 'We arrive at' | translate }} {{hour}}</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! You (and SO) are great! Sorry for asking such a dumb question, but I was getting mad since half an hour... Sometimes you really need a different POV!

Comment: It happens to the best of us.